# T0lte model number

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-note-2

This could be obvious I have a Note 2 and the Model number in the phone is the CyanogenMod T0lte. When I got the phone it already had a custom Rom so I never go to see the original modle number. With the official 4.4 update I want to try it out but Samsung does not recognize this modle number so what is the model number for T0lte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely `GT-N7105`, the international version. You can find the other models in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_II).

Comment: That was my guess but I was very unsure. Thanks